# How to replace database reference inside SQL script when building database project in Azure Pipeline

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-devops, configuration

I have a database project which has another DB reference in sql scripts While trying to publish to Azure DevOps Pipelines, I can't access the referenced database, because in each release stage we have different database, and we can't just hard code the value of database name.

For example:

```
select * from [ReferencedDB].dbo.table1
```

ReferencedDB will different databases in each environments e.g. QA,UAT ...etc.

Is there a way to read value inside sql script from a config file (where the values of this config file is changes using variables groups)? I mean something like web.config in .NET project.

Comment: You can use SQLCMD scripting variables in place of the database name (e.g. `[$(ReferencedDB)].dbo.table1`).  With SQLCMD, invoke with arguments like `-v ReferencedDB=QA"` to replace the value at runtime or similarly with sqlpackage.exe. The variables can also be defined/set in your azure-pipelines.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to read value inside sql script from a config file (where the values of this config file is changes using variables groups)?

Of course you can implement it in Azure Devops.

You could use PowerShell Script to get the Database Name in the Web.config file. Then you could set the value as Pipeline Variable(Use [Logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#overview)). Finally, you can use Replace Tokens task(From [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)) to replace the parameters in the sql script.

Here is my example:

Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>  
    <add name="myConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;database=mydatabase;" />
  </connectionStrings>
....
</configuration>
```

Sql Command in Sql Script file:

```
select * from #{Database}#.dbo.table1
```

PowerShell Script:

```
$webConfigFile = [xml](Get-Content "FilePath\Web.config")

$connString = $webConfigFile.configuration.connectionStrings.add
Write-Host "Connection String $($connString.name): $($connString.connectionString)"
$dbRegex = "((Initial Catalog)|((Database)))\s*=(?<ic>[a-z\s0-9]+?);"
$found = $connString.connectionString -match $dbRegex
if ($found)
{
   Write-Host "Database: $($Matches["ic"])"
   $DatabaseName = $($Matches["ic"])
 }



echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Database]$DatabaseName"
```

Release Definition: Set the `Target files -> **/*.sql`

[image]

Result:

```
select * from mydatabase.dbo.table1
```